# Remove lot with given number

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to remove the lot with a given number. It seems to return with null everytime, or respond with lot not found. What's up?

Could the problem be elsewhere rather than this code? removeLot is the method that needs fixing. I'm a bit confused here.

```
public class Auction
{
// The list of Lots in this auction.
private ArrayList<Lot> lots;
// The number that will be given to the next lot entered
// into this auction.
private int nextLotNumber;

private ArrayList<Lot> Unsold;

private int  lotNumber;


/**
 * Create a new auction.
 */
public Auction()
{
    lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
    nextLotNumber = 1;
}

/**
 * Enter a new lot into the auction.
 * @param description A description of the lot.
 * Adds lot to ArrayList
 */
public void enterLot(String description)
{
    lots.add(new Lot(nextLotNumber, description));
    nextLotNumber++;

}

/**
 * Show the full list of lots in this auction.
 */
public void showLots()
{
    for(Lot lot : lots) {
        System.out.println(lot.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Make a bid for a lot.
 * A message is printed indicating whether the bid is
 * successful or not.
 * 
 * @param lotNumber The lot being bid for.
 * @param bidder The person bidding for the lot.
 * @param value  The value of the bid.
 * If successful bid it removes lot from ArrayList
 */
public void makeABid(int lotNumber, Person bidder, long value)
{
    Lot selectedLot = getLot(lotNumber);
    if(selectedLot != null) {
        Bid bid = new Bid(bidder, value);
        boolean successful = selectedLot.bidFor(bid);
        if(successful) {
            System.out.println("The bid for lot number " +
                               lotNumber + " was successful.");                    
        }
        else {
            // Report which bid is higher.
            Bid highestBid = selectedLot.getHighestBid();
            System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                               " already has a bid of: " +
                               highestBid.getValue());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Return the lot with the given number. Return null
 * if a lot with this number does not exist.
 * @param lotNumber The number of the lot to return.
 * No longer determines the lot number according to index number.
 */
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
{
    if((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {
        // The number seems to be reasonable.
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);
        // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
        // right lot.
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                               selectedLot.getNumber() +
                               " was returned instead of " +
                               lotNumber);
            // Don't return an invalid lot.
            selectedLot = null;
        }
        return selectedLot;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                           " does not exist.");
        return null;
    }
}


    /**
 * Look for closed lots. Return highest bid and bidder name if sold.
 * If lot not sold print not sold.
 */
public void close(int lotNumber, String description)
{
    for(Lot lot : lots) 
    {
        System.out.println(lotNumber + description); //print lot number and description.
        Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid(); //get the highest bid for the lot.
        if (highestBid != null) 
        {
            String name = highestBid.getBidder().getName(); 
            System.out.println(name + " " + highestBid.getValue()); //print bidder and highest bid value
        }     
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not sold"); //if not sold print "Not sold"
        }
    }
}

       /**
 * Returns the list of unsold lots.
 * If sold print sold statement.
 */
public ArrayList<Lot> getUnsold()
{  
    ArrayList<Lot> unsold = new ArrayList<Lot>();
    for(Lot lot : lots) 
    {
        Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
        lotNumber = lot.getNumber();
      if (highestBid != null) 
        {

        System.out.println("Lot number " + lotNumber + " is sold"); //retuern "Sold" is highestBid
        }
       else
        {
        System.out.println(lotNumber); //print bidder and highest bid value
        unsold.add(lot); // you are missing this
        }
    }
    return unsold;
}

    /**
 * Remove the lot with the given lot number.
 * @param number The number of the lot removed.
 * @return The Lot with the given number, or null if there is no such lot.
 */
public Lot romoveLot(int number)
{
    if((number >= 1) && (number < nextLotNumber)) {
        // The number seems to be reasonable.
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(number);
        // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
        // right lot.
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != number) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                               selectedLot.getNumber() +
                               " was returned instead of " +
                               number);
            // Don't return an invalid lot.
            selectedLot = null;
        }
        else {
             lots.remove(number);
            }
            return selectedLot;

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Lot number: " + number +
                           " does not exist.");
        return null;
    } 
 }

}
```

Comment: As a side note, you seem to be trying to roll your own map (possibly with a linked-list like structure?!?!).  If this is not part of a school assignment, you may want to just use one of the maps Java provides.

Comment: What are you passing the method? This is your logic - you decide when you return null. Does the number you pass in meet all of the criteria you are coding into your method to be removed?

Comment: What is the type of the `lots` variable?

Comment: Check your console - does it display the FIRST log output you make (failing your first if statement), or the second?

Comment: I've posted the full code to the class. What is wrong with removeLot?

Comment: You're still not showing how the removeLot is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommed using a `HashMap` or any other hash table implementation based on your need.
 something like `HashMap<Lot> lots= new HashMap<Lot>();`

Store all `Lot` variables into the map and simply apply

```
lot.contains(numberYouWantToCheck);
```